# maven liquibase plugin does not find jitpack dependency

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I have a very strange problem. Some time ago I forked `liquibase-hibernate` because I found a [bug](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/issues/61) and solved it.

While this [pull request](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/pull/83) is beeing accepted, I deployed my `liquibase-hibernate4` plugin into local artifactory and everything was Ok.

But now it comes the problem. I have to use this dependency in a project and I cannot use my local artifactory. So I use JitPack repository this way:

Added JitPack in `pom.xml` repository:

```
<repositories>
...
  <repository>
    <id>jitpack.io</id>
    <url>http://jitpack.io</url>
  </repository>
...
</repositories>
```

Then added dependency:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.malaguna</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate</artifactId>
  <version>liquibase-hibernate4-3.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I run `mvn compile` or `mvn package` and it works well. But I also have configured `maven-liquibase-plugin` and included the same dependency inside, because other way the plugin does not work.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>

  <configuration>
    <propertyFile>target/classes/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
  </configuration>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.malaguna</groupId>
      <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>liquibase-hibernate4-3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

....
```

Now, when I run `mvn resources:resources liquibase:diff` I can see how maven tries to get my liquibase-hibernate artifact from maven central:

```
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff (default-cli) @ project ---
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/malaguna/liquibase-hibernate/liquibase-hibernate4-3.6.1/liquibase-hibernate-liquibase-hibernate4-3.6.1.jar
...
```

And then it fails

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff 
(default-cli) on project xxxxx: Execution default-cli of goal
org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1:diff failed: 
Plugin org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.4.1 or one of its 
dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact 
com.github.malaguna:liquibase-hibernate:jar:liquibase-hibernate4-3.6.1 in central 
(http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Why it is maven trying to download the artifact from maven central, instead jitpack, when invoked from maven-liquibase-plugin? How can I avoid this?

As I stated before, when running compile or package it works well and the artifact is downloaded.

Comment: Have any proxies setup in `~/.m2/settings.xml`?

Comment: No. I have two settings one for the artifactory and other with no configuration at all. It works well with artifactory, because artifactory finds jitpack artifact by means of codehaus-cache. The problem comes if I don't want to use artifactory.

Comment: Does the liquibase-maven-plugin respect the "outer" repository settings? It seems like they are spinning up a separate configuration which does _not_ take into account your repositories configuration.

Comment: Your comment is very nice. I have no idea how `liquibase-maven-plugin` works. Can I configure this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven distinguish between artifact repositories and plugin repositories, see [Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) and [Plugin_Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Repositories). So in your case you have to provide

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>http://jitpack.io</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

The dependency of a plugin is defined via

```xml
<plugin>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            ....
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

as you already noticed.

Comment: I have just tested your solution and it works. I edited your answer because of an error it is `pluginRepository` instead `repository`, but once changed it works perfectly. Thanks! I tried to give you the bounty, but I can't, I have to wait four hours before.